Prestashop 1.7 Add ISBN value from product table to delivery-slip.tpl
Let me try to explain what I'm looking for:
We use the ISBN field in products options for adding packing size information. Everything is fine when the order is passed directly in Prestashop. But when we import orders from Amazon via the Common-Services module, the ISBN in the order-detail table is left blank. This information is obviously either not imported or is blocked somehow.
I already made changes to delivery-slip.product-tap.tpl:
{if empty($order_detail.product_isbn)}
                        ---
                    {else}
                        {$order_detail.product_isbn}
                    {/if}

Like I said, this is perfect for Prestashop orders only.
For imported orders, I have to access the ISBN directly from the product table instead of the order-detail table but using {$product.isbn} does not work.
What code do I have to add and where do I have to add it (I guess in HTMLTemplateDeliverySlip.php)  in order to access the ISBN value directly from the products table?
I tried this but it gives Error 500. I guess because $product cannot be used in the HTMLTemplateDeliverySlip.php
{if empty($product.isbn)}
---
{else}
   {$product.isbn}
{/if}

I need something like
getValue('SELECT isbn FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE id_product = '.(int) $order_detail.product_id)

Thank you in advance.

My solution is to populate ISBN values from product to order_detail.
This can be easily done with an override of OrderDetail class.
Just create a file called OrderDetail.php, inside override/classes/order directory (create it if doesn't exists), with this content:
<?php

class OrderDetail extends OrderDetailCore
{
    public function save($null_values = false, $auto_date = true)
    {
        if ($this->product_id && (is_null($this->product_isbn) || $this->product_isbn == '')) {
            $this->product_isbn = (string) Db::getInstance()->getValue(
                "SELECT `isbn` FROM `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "product` WHERE `id_product` = " . (int) $this->product_id
            );
        }

        return parent::save($null_values, $auto_date);
    }
}

Then remove the file class_index from var/cache/prod directory to ensure PrestaShop will take your new OrderDetail overriden class.
The intention is: when an OrderDetail it will be saved, check if there is product_id but not product_isbn, and in this case take the ISBN value from product table.
However, as Amazon module from Common Services is a commercial module, and I guess you paid for it, in your place I would ask them for just add product ISBN to order details when an order is imported, so you can forget about the override.
